# Display id value

Tags: jquery, html

Could someone help me out, I'm trying to display the values to what these id's are linked to. 
here is a part from my html

```
<body>
<div id='what'></div>
<div id='when'></div>
<div id='where'></div>
</div>
</body>
```

and here is my j query

```
var details = {what:'fun and games',
               when:'Thursday',
               where:'Jeffs House'}
```

So basically I want the values  ^^ here to be displayed. 
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could loop through the properties of this object and set the corresponding values:

```
var performance = {
    what: 'fun and games',
    when: 'Thursday',
    where: 'Jeffs House'
};

for (var key in performance) {
    if (performance.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        $('#' + key).html(performance[key]);
    }
}
```

And here's a [`live demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/hV5H4/).

Comment: Hmm, I understand how it works in the live demo but for some reason it won't display it in my code.

Comment: Well without seeing your code I really don't see how we could help. Maybe you could try to provide a jsfiddle illustrating the problem?

Comment: My code is basically pretty much the same as that. Literally no idea what is stopping it from working

Comment: Then post your code!!! How do you expect me telling you what's wrong with it??? Show your full markup as seen by the browser.

Comment: But in the example you have shown you haven't included `jquery.js` properly. You have just placed a `<script>` tag pointing to `jquery.min.js` and some `test.js` but those files do not exist. If you want to link to jquery in jsfiddle, simply select the option in the `Chose Framework` combobox on the top left corner. Here's an updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/CsRGk/2/

Comment: But in my actual code those files exist, I only posted to jsfiddle so you could see it. So I still have no idea why it wont work